# How to create TPM Virtual Smart Card With Attestation in C++

Tags: c++, tpm

I use following code to create virtual smart card with Attestation

```
HRESULT CoCreateInstanceAsAdmin(HWND hwnd, REFCLSID rclsid, REFIID riid, void **ppv)
{
    BIND_OPTS3 bo;
    WCHAR wszCLSID[50];
    WCHAR wszMon[300];

    StringFromGUID2(rclsid, wszCLSID, sizeof(wszCLSID) / sizeof(wszCLSID[0]));
    HRESULT hr = StringCchPrintfW(wszMon, sizeof(wszMon) / sizeof(wszMon[0]), L"Elevation:Administrator!new:%s", wszCLSID);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    return hr;
    memset(&bo, 0, sizeof(bo));
    bo.cbStruct = sizeof(bo);
    bo.hwnd = hwnd;
    bo.dwClassContext = CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER;
    return CoGetObject(wszMon, &bo, riid, ppv);  
}

int main()
{
    Byte pin[] = "12345678";

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    HWND hwnd = NULL;
    ITpmVirtualSmartCardManager3 *pObj = NULL;
    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
    hr = CoCreateInstanceAsAdmin(
        hwnd,
        CLSID_TpmVirtualSmartCardManager,
        IID_ITpmVirtualSmartCardManager,
        (void**)&pObj);     

    //ITpmVirtualSmartCardManager *pObj = NULL;
    auto friendly = L"Friendly";
    std::wstring wstring = L"";;
    LPWSTR out = &wstring[0];
    BYTE adminPin[] = "123456789";
    DWORD size = sizeof(adminPin);
    BOOL boot;

    hr = pObj->CreateVirtualSmartCardWithAttestation(friendly, 
        TPMVSC_DEFAULT_ADMIN_ALGORITHM_ID, 
        adminPin, 24, 
        NULL, 0, 
        adminPin, size, 
        pin, sizeof(pin),       
        NULL,       
        0,
        TPMVSC_ATTESTATION_AIK_AND_CERTIFICATE,
        true,
        NULL,
        &out
        );

    return 0;
}
```

But when call the CreateVirtualSmartCardWithAttestation get following error

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but if you return prematurely from the function, there is no write to `ppv`, so `pObj` is still `NULL` and you don't seem to check against that.

Comment: But `pObj` is not `NULL` and has a value

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're trying to reference `CreateVirtualSmartCardWithAttestation` while using `IID_ITpmVirtualSmartCardManager`, which does not have that function declared.

If you wish to use `CreateVirtualSmartCardWithAttestation`, you must replace `IID_ITpmVirtualSmartCardManager` with `IID_ITpmVirtualSmartCardManager3`.